React to specific branch getting deleted on GitHub
According to the documentation, the 'push' event is triggered each time there is:

A push to the repository
A branch being created
A branch being deleted

This lead to my yml file looking like this:
name: Manage Branch
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "ReleaseCandidates/**"
      - "main"
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions:
  contents: read
jobs:
  HandleEvent:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    #Only run for 'main' if it is a regular push or a manual launch.
    if: ${{ github.ref_name != 'main' || (!github.event.deleted && !github.event.created) }}
    steps:
      - name: Handles the event on the buildserver.
        run: #Do stuff

As you can see, I wish to be notified of my 'main' and 'ReleaseCandidates' branches changing, including new release candidates being created as well as deleted. The purpose is control of an external buildserver.
This seems to work well enough for actual pushes as well as creations, however the event doesn't seem to trigger for deletions.
Of course I could just create a separate condition on 'delete', but I was wondering, if I maybe am doing something wrong or misinterpreted the documentation in that aspect.
Maybe the filters are the problem?
But how else would I listen to 'deletions of ReleaseCandidates'?

The documentation also mentions that there is a delete event. Have you tried to see if that gets triggered when you expect? I don't disagree with your reading of the docs; I'm just wondering if there is a workaround that gets you the notification you want.

I did read about the 'delete' trigger, @larsks. And I have seen it get triggered, however it doesn't seem to support branch filtering. Additionally, the docs explicitly state: To subscribe to only branch and tag deletions, use the delete webhook event. <-- Mind the 'only'. I am not 'only' interested in branch and tag deletions, but 'also' interested in them.

Sure, but your workflow can have multiple triggers, including both push and delete.

Which is what I ended up doing, @larsk (see the answer I posted for those who come looking?). What irks me is, that the observed functionality and the documented functionality are different in this aspect. If GitHub fixes the issue, I'll have an event that'll fire twice now...once on delete and once on push. The (partial) duplication didn't exactly help the readability either, if you ask me.

Because 'push' (although on the default branch 'main') apparently does not get triggered on branch deletion (possibly due to filter criteria), this is what I ended up doing in the end.
name: Manage Branch
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "ReleaseCandidates/**"
      - "main"
  delete:
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions:
  contents: read
jobs:
  HandleEvent:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    #Only run for 'main' if it is a regular push or a manual launch.
    if: ${{ github.event_name != 'delete' && (github.ref_name != 'main' || (!github.event.deleted && !github.event.created)) }}
    steps:
      - name: Handles the event on the buildserver.
        run: #Do stuff on push

  HandleDelete:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    #Only run deletions for 'ReleaseCandidate' branches. (event.ref contains the name of the deleted branch)
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'delete' && github.event.ref_type == 'branch' && startsWith(github.event.ref, 'ReleaseCandidates/') }}
    steps:
      - name: Handles the deletion on the buildserver.
        run: #Do stuff on delete

Hardly ideal, but it works well enough. Of course it will fire twice if 'push' should start working as described, but better fire twice than 'not at all'.
